# Working with Selected IDs in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a database with two tables. The `ssi_processed_files_prod` table contains file information including the created date and a boolean indicating if the data has been deleted. The `data` table contains the actual data the boolean references.

I want to get a list of IDs over the age of 45 days from the `file_info` table, delete the associated rows from the `data` table, then set the boolean from `file_info` to True to indicate the data has been deleted.

```
file_log_test= Table('ssi_processed_files_prod', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
stmt = select([file_log_test.columns.id])
stmt = stmt.where(func.datediff(text('day'), 
file_log_test.columns.processing_end_time, func.getDate()) > 45)
connection = engine.connect()
results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()
```

This query returns the correct results, however, I have not been able to work with the output effectively.

Comment: What does working correctly mean?

Comment: Better said I have found documentation to help me understand how to create a query that can use the output of id's from the above query to do the delete and update operation. The above code works fine. It is the next steps I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

For those who would like to know the answer. This was based on reading the Essential SQL Alchemy book. The initial block of cod was correct, but I had to flatten the results into a list. From there I could use the in_() conjuction to work with the list of ids. This allowed me to delete rows from the relevant table and update data status in anohter.

```
 file_log_test= Table('ssi_processed_files_prod', metadata, autoload=True, 
 autoload_with=engine)
 stmt = select([file_log_test.columns.id])
 stmt = stmt.where(func.datediff(text('day'), 
 file_log_test.columns.processing_end_time, func.getDate()) > 45)
 connection = engine.connect()
 results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()

 ids_to_delete = [x[0] for x in results]
 d = delete(data).where(data.c.filename_id.in_(ids_to_delete))
 connection.execute(d)
```